# file_put_contents(/homepages/storage/framework/views/c8d540ced881ee3d14baa6e1259a7deab143b7fa.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 5 project that I copied from my friend with FTP to work on it in locally. I ran `composer install` to install the vendor.

The server is up, but when I enter *localhost:8000*, it shows me this error:

> file_put_contents(/homepages/17/d595652778/htdocs/oneQ/storage/framework/views/c8d540ced881ee3d14baa6e1259a7deab143b7fa.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: make sure the folder `/storage/framework/views/` exists and has correct permissions

Comment: I did it but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: it worked thank you very much.
What's the role of this command?

Comment: this command is used to clear and re cache  config settings cached by framework.

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't worked for me:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

However this one has worked:

```
php artisan view:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i try to file config.php "delete file bootstrap/cahce/config.php" and its working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and i managed to fix it by running:

```
composer install
```

from within the project directory or the container if you a using Docker-based development tool such as ddev.